Product of topologies and $\mathbb{R}^2$
In many places I have seen written that the product topology of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ with both spaces equipped with the usual topology is equivalent to the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
The argument that I have seen most to justify this is the fact that the cartesian product of open intervals can be covered by an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology (that is, an open disc, with a certain radius and so on). Besides, any open disc in the plane can be covered by the product of two open intervals. This seems right for me.
What I don't understand is why that means that the product of real numbers equipped with usual topology with itself and the plane with the usual topology are the same. Why are they equivalent if the open sets of both spaces are different? As said above, in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ the open sets would be the generated by the cartesian product of intervals, with the form $(a,b) \times (c,d), a < b, c < d$, and in $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be the generated by discs with aspect $B(x_0,r), r > 0$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
It is the fact that each open set of both spaces can be covered by an open set of the other one enough to show that they are the same? Shouldn't be also open sets exactly equal? As far as I'm concerned, cartesian product of open intervals are different to open discs.

The open sets are exactly equal. The point is that if you can write an open set in one topology as a union of open sets in the other, then it is also open in that other topology (by definition).

Any union of open sets is open, so if a set can be covered by open sets, it is open.

How can you write, for example, the disc $B((0,0),1)$, with center in the origin and radius $1$ as the union of product of open intervals? And viceversa with $(0,1) \times (0,1)$?

@EmmyN. For each $x \in B(0, 1)$ there's some $r > 0$ with $B(x, r) \subseteq B(0, 1)$. You can then find an open square $S_x \subset B(x, r)$ containing $x$ (just pick side lengths sufficiently small). Do this for all points of $B(0, 1)$; then you can write $B(0, 1) = \bigcup_{x \in B(0, 1)} S_x$ so it is open in the product topology. The same idea applies to the other direction.

The bases are of course different, but the topology they generate is the same.

To compare basis elements, consider meditate on these two images.

To sum up some of the comments: You are confusing the collection of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a choice of basis of open sets. An open ball is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but so is the union of two (or ten) open balls, and so is the union of an open ball and an open rectangle, and so is an open pentagon, an open half-plane, and numerous other sets.
The open balls form a basis of the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, which means that the open sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are all sets you can get by starting with open balls and then using the operations of unions and finite intersections. The collection of open rectangles is different than the collection of open balls, but both generate the same topology in this way.
To see they generate the same topology, it suffices to show that any open rectangle is a union of open balls, and vice versa. We could try to do some fancy tiling or construction for this. But since the unions don't need to be finite, or even countable, we can do something much more straightforward:
Claim:
1. Any open rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the union of the open balls it contains.
2. Any open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the union of the open rectangles it contains.
To prove 1., we need to show that any point $p$ in an open rectangle is contained in an open ball which is itself contained in the rectangle. There is some distance $d > 0$ from $p$ to the boundary of the rectangle, and so we can use the open ball with radius $\frac{d}{2}$, centered on $p$.
The proof of the second part is exactly the same as the first, except we swap the words "ball" and "rectangle" and change "radius" to "side lengths".
